# Shared model to access SQL Server from UWP

Tags: sql-server, uwp

Learnt that UWP app won't allow to directly access SQL Server or any DB on the network - got to use windows service or web service.  My question is that if I have a shared project that has models connecting to remote SQL Server, can I refer to these models in ViewModels in UWP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the project to the UWP　solution if the models project have not any other DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but checkout the Contoso UWP sample Application. It a sample database application following best practices.  It should be an excellent place to start:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database